Ricci scalar on TOV metric
Hi i computed the ricci scalar for the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff metric and obtained $R=\frac{8\pi G}{c^{4}}(\varepsilon - p)$ where $\varepsilon$ is the energy density and $p$ the pressure. I can't find it anywhere this result. Anyone knows if someone did it or if that this result is correct?

The correct result is $R=\frac{8\pi G}{c^{4}}(\varepsilon - 3 p)$. There must be an error somewhere in your derivation.

Oh thank you! where can i found this result? @JanG

This is exactly what you get when you trace both sides of Einstein's equation. Have you already done this?

oh okay, i'll try that way. I looked at book (carrolls) for the expression of the Ricci scalar for spherical and stationary metric, then used the metric coefficients of TOV metric. Isn't there a factor 2 involved in the left side? @JanG

Don't worry, solved @JanG
